# Prove that $(1/3)×(4^{n+1}-1) \mod 2*3^m$ cycles after $3^m$ terms

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've observed that the sequence

$S: 1, 5, 21, 85, 341, 1365, 5461 \ldots$ $\; \; \; T_n = \frac{1}{3}×(4^{n+1}-1)$

has some cool properties when you change it to mod  $2×3^m$

m=0

$S \; mod \; 2 : \; 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 \ldots$ {Cycle length 1}

m=1

$S \; mod \; 6 : \; 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 3 \ldots$ {Cycle length 3}

m=2

$S \; mod \; 18 : \; 1, 5, 3, 13, 17, 15, 7, 11, 9, 1 \ldots$ {Cycle length 9}

I'd like to prove 2 things - I'm fairly sure the second is a corollary of the first.

1: That the cycle length is $3^m$.

- I'm assuming it is to do with 4 and 3 being co-prime, but I can't see how to use this.

2: That all odd numbers below the mod number are in this cycle.

- I think it is enough to say this is forced by the pigeon hole principle?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did you decide to take it mod $2 \cdot 3^m$ instead of just mod $3^m$?

Comment: It's relevant to the problem I'm working on, so it was less of a choice, more of a moment of "oh hey, I've spotted a pattern and this is the formula for it" @MichaelTong

Comment: @MichaelTong - $2 \cdot 3^m$ is $\phi(3^{m+1})$ - the order of the group of invertible elements $\mod 3^{m+1}$. I guess that's why the OP was interested in this in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle length is indeed $3^m$, and the second statement does indeed follow from the first through the pigeon-hole principle.

You can easily transform the problem to the following statement that needs proof: for every $m  \ge 0$, the order of $4 \mod 3^{m+1}$ is $3^m$. (That is, the least strictly positive $k$ so that $3^{m+1} | (4^k - 1)$ is $3^m$.)

That $k = 3^m$ works is Euler's theorem (generalizing Fermat's little theorem).

The rest of the proof is by induction on $m$. The statement is true for $m=0$. Then, let $x$ be the order of $4 \mod 3^{m+2}$. Since $k = 3^{m+1}$ would work, it is easy to show $x \mid 3^{m+1}$. So it suffices to show that $k = 3^m$ doesn't work. ("Work" or "doesn't work" means $3^{m+2} \mid (4^k-1)$.)

Now: put $k = 3^m$ and $l = 3^{m-1}$. We know that $3^{m+1}$ divides $4^k - 1$, but it does not divide $4^l-1$ (induction hypothesis). Then:

$$4^k-1 = 4^{3l}-1 = (4^l-1)(4^{2l} + 4^l + 1).$$

Now the first factor is divisible by $3^m$ but not by $3^{m+1}$, and the second factor is divisible by 3 but not by 9 (prove!) So $4^k-1$ is divisible by $3^{m+1}$ (which we already knew from Euler's theorem), but it is **not** divisible by $3^{n+2}$ - which is what we needed. End of story.

**Edit**:   Hmm... looking at this again after many days... I kind of rushed it. $\phi(3^{m+1}) = 2 \cdot 3^m$, not $3^m$, so there is a bit of argument missing. By Euler's theorem $4^{2 \cdot 3^m} -1$ is divisible by $3^{m+1}$; but $4^{2\cdot 3^m} - 1 = (4^{3^m} -1)(4^{3^m}+1)$, and the second factor is not divisible by 3, so the first factor must be divisible by $3^{m+1}$. A similar argument may be needed again later in the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much! EoS. Needs to replace Q.E.D. Who speaks Latin nowadays anyway?